# Should I make a RESTful API using Cloud Functions or call Firebase and Firestore in app?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently creating a marketplace mobile application from scratch and I'm using React Native for the front-end part and Firebase for the backend (using Firebase and Firestore).

I am wondering wether :

- I should **create a RESTful API using cloud functions and express** to create API endpoints (that would connect to firebase and firestore) that I'd call from my redux actions in my React Native app (using redux thunk).
- or, I should **call firebase and firestore directly from redux** actions.

I see couple pros and cons for each method.

**Restful API pros :**

- Safer as I can check and manipulate submitted data more easily
- Custom API reply (I can manipulate the return data)

**Restful API cons :**

- Probably slower as I would have to call an API endpoint that will then call firebase and/or firestore.
- Won't be as easy to set listeners on firestore data

What do you think about it ?

Which option should I choose knowing that I predict that the app will get a few thousand users daily. I want it to be as fast and safe as possible and be able to set listeners for notifications purposes.

Comment: Without knowing very specifically what you're trying to do, this is entirely a matter of opinion.  I've written extensively about this in a [blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c).  If you want to open up a general discussion for your specific use case, I suggest posting to a discussion forum that allows it, such as [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should mix them, if you have to manage users, products or etc. Firebase produces client and admin sdk that has different roles. If you haven't need manage any data of products or users or etc. you can simply use client sdk.

My advise is you can use admin sdk on API (server-side) and feel free to use client sdk on your clients.

Use as managements on API, listening data, realtime chat etc. via client sdk.

You can check [admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?gclid=CjwKCAiAtK79BRAIEiwA4OskBqJJPEpfu7u54X-Hsa4gztPEXWOziu0th1lIR-MEj53dUEVCvyXmtxoCBNYQAvD_BwE) and [client](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js) sdk. Also npm packages for React Native [here](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react-native-firebase).

Comment: Data which need to be updated on real-time for example Like, Dislike, Rating that should call directly to firebase from client. For other then that recommend to use admin sdk on server side. If you intends to do authorization then must use admin sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing will be of help, you can try:

- Listen for small amounts of data using the client SDK
- Write and sort data using the cloud functions

In my experience, writing to a firebase database that uses ordered ids (in my case) leads to some huge problems in the long run. I lost a good chunk of data when my app accidentally wrote to a root index instead of a child index when the app was resumed from inactivity because the android system cleared the RAM.

Also, for notification, use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging).